# How to track inactive and hot partitions in azure cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to see the partitions where there is a lot of reads and writes 
I also want to see the partitions where there's been no crud operations for long, so that I can clean it up
is that possible in cosmos db ?

Comment: You want to delete some partitioned data?

Comment: I want to know what are the partitions which are hot or inactive, having to read or write on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: I want to know what are the partitions which are hot or inactive,
>   having to read or write on it

According to your further description,you want to know the distribute situations of requests cross your multiple partitions.

Actually,that metric could be touched in the Azure Portal Metrics `Throughput` tab.

[image]

You could determine the throughput distribution of any partitioned container broken down by partitions.More details,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics#determine-the-throughput-distribution-across-partitions).